# Why is array considered better than STL containers?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, graph, stl

`array` vs. `std::queue`, which is better in terms of time and why?

I have written one graph processing algorithm in which frontier vertices are stored in `std::queue` and are accessed using `push_back()` and `pop_front()`. When I re-implemented the frontier with array with front and end pointers pointing to the start and end of the frontier vertices, I get the better result in terms of time. Is array really faster than queue for large enough size of data?

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges.  If you need a queue structure why use something that is not a queue?

Comment: Accessing elements in an array and in a vector are both O(1). The time difference is, if anything, negligible. What *does* differ is that a vector is *dynamic*, when you add elements to a vector it might need to resize itself, which includes copying the existing data. That can be slow. If you know approximately the number of elements needed, you can reserve that amount for the vector and the speed difference goes back to just about zero. If you want a container with a compile-time fixed number of elements, use `std::array` instead.

Comment: One is static, the other is dynamic.

Comment: There are too many missing details here. Did you compile with optimizations? Did you use a data structure that gave you more functionality than you needed? Does your code still have as much functionality?

Comment: @NathanOliver considering I have plenty of memory, if queue is dynamic and wastes time resizing as said by Joachim, then using array with maximum required size could be option if it really is faster. I want to know  for sure.

Comment: @GManNickG I just changed the data container from queue(I am using pop_front and push_back functions only) to array. And I did not compile with optimizations

Comment: If you didn't compile with optimizations, asking about performance is meaningless. You tied both the compiler's hands behind its back. Was this a dynamic array you changed to, or fixed-size?

Comment: @GManNickG fixed size and it is not circular. Just an array of size of maximum number of elements possible

Comment: @BibekBhattarai: So this falls under the "the data structure did too much" category. That said I'd like to see the results with optimizations turned on. But if you have a max element count and `std::queue` does not, it will keep trying to grow things as much as it needs and that has bookkeeping overhead. If you needed that behavior, then `std::queue` would be better than array. Boost has a `circular_buffer` class, for example, which is closer to what most people want when they have some hard cap on element count. If you posted more code  (but minimal) we could review the options.

Answer (score 1):

The array is faster for most machines, because the contiguous elements of an array can be loaded in the same cache line (or pre loaded to the cache on a pre-need basis). Since a L1 cache read is 200 times faster than a main memory access, anything that requires a pointer fetch, will likely not be in cache and takes the much longer main memory fetch cycle.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Comment: Implementations of std::queue tend to allocate contiguous memory blocks of increasing size, (e.g. a block for the first 16 elements, then a block for he next 32 elements) which are as large or larger than the cache line size. So the difference becomes is whether or not subsequent cache misses are sequential or not, which generally is less of an impact.